# unable to upload file using multer with Typescipt?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, file-upload, multer

I am using express as framework and Typescript as language. I want to upload a file using multer module. But i am not able to upload. I have routes which has a `product.ts` file and a `Server.ts` which has server configuration.

Routes/product.ts

```
import { Request, Response, Router, NextFunction } from "express";
import { ProductService } from '../services/product'
import multer from 'multer';
let prosvc = new ProductService()
const router = Router();

var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

router.post("/addfile",upload.array('images',1), async (req: Request, res: Response,next :NextFunction) => {
  try {
    console.log("request" )
    res.send({data:req.file})
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.sendStatus(400);
  }
});
```

Server.ts

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import "express-async-errors";
import BaseRouter from "./routes";

// Init express
const app = express();

// Add APIs
app.use("/api", BaseRouter);

export default app;
```

tsConfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitAny":false,
    "paths": {
      "@shared/*": ["src/shared/*"],
      "@server": ["src/Server"]
    },
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "spec/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["src/public/"]
}
```

index.ts

```
import "./LoadEnv"; // Must be the first import
import app from "@server";
import "reflect-metadata";

const port = Number(process.env.PORT || 3001);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Express server started on port: " + port);

});
```

Uploads folder is getting created but file is not getting uploaded & i don't any error as well.
Please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: What's the output of `res.send({data:req.file})` ? How do you upload from the client side, could you provide the code as well?

Comment: Output is {}. a blank json obect i get. I upload file with Postman formdata in body.